# How to transfer newly added data in dynamodb to s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue to transfer dynamodb table data to s3 bucket. Its working totally fine. But I am unable to transfer newly added data from dynamo to s3. Its again transferring whole table of dynamodb to s3, I only want to transfer newly added data to s3 on a regular interval. How do I accomplish it?

Comment: Through glue job, or any way is good?

Comment: My region does not have Data-Pipeline service. So i am using Glue. Using Glue would be preferable.

Comment: Have you tried the Job bookmark feature in Glue? (Have you tried to accomplish this using Apache Nifi?)

Comment: Yes, I have tried Job bookmark but it didn't work. Later on StackOverflow and aws forums, I found that Job bookmark feature only works from s3 to s3. So now I am implementing my desired functionality using different aws service.

Comment: if it's an insert only table, you can use dynamoDB steams along with kinesis data stream and kinesis firehose to write the records out to s3. If its not a insert only table and the requirement is only to write a new item, then use lambda with dynamoDB stream to write the data out to s3 during CREATE operation